# How to show game server's ping on the screen?

Tags: javascript, typescript, actionscript-3

Is there a code to show the game server's ping on the screen as in the bellow example?

```
this.tfEnter.text = ShowPing + " ms";
```

or it may be in the examples, the codes on some topics do not work very well
Channel List Image:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/x7BG5h8.png]

```
package cso2.ui.lobbyServerObjs
{
   import cso2.com.gh.controls.BaseTileItem;
   import cso2.ui.SystemHelpPopup;
   import flash.display.*;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;
   import flash.net.URLRequest;
   import flash.text.TextField;
   
   
   
   public class LobbyServerChannelListItem extends BaseTileItem
   {
       
      
      public var bg:MovieClip;
      
      public var tfName:TextField;
      
      public var tfRecommand:TextField;
      
      public var tfEnter:TextField;
      
      private var url:String;
      
      private var Lamp:Class;
      
      private var compressor:Object;
      
      private var label:String;
      
      
      
      public function LobbyServerChannelListItem()
      {
         super();
      }
      
      override protected function configUI() : void
      {
         super.configUI();
      }
      
      override protected function handleMouseRollOver(param1:MouseEvent) : void
      {
         super.handleMouseRollOver(param1);
         if(data.recommendContent)
         {
            SystemHelpPopup.getInstance().show(this,data.recommendContent,300,2);
         }
      }
      
      override protected function handleMouseRollOut(param1:MouseEvent) : void
      {
         super.handleMouseRollOut(param1);
         SystemHelpPopup.getInstance().hide();
      }
      
      function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number) : Number
      {
         return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum;
      }
      
      override public function setData(param1:Object) : void
      {
         var rect:Shape = null;
         var ldr:Loader = null;
         var url:String = null;
         var urlReq:URLRequest = null;
         var _loc5_:* = undefined;
         super.setData(param1);
         if(param1 == null || isMax)
         {
            this.bg.gotoAndStop(4);
            this.tfRecommand.text = "";
            this.tfEnter.text = "";
            this.tfName.text = "";
            this.tfEnter.textColor = "CSO2_BIGCITY_SERVER_COLOR";
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
         }
         this.enabled = true;
         this.tfName.htmlText = param1.label;
         if(param1.recommend)
         {
            this.tfRecommand.text = "CSO2_UI_CHANNEL_RECOMMAND";
         }
         else
         {
            this.tfRecommand.text = "";
         }
         if(param1.ban)
         {
            this.tfEnter.textColor = "CSO2_UI_CHANNEL_BAN_COLOR";
            this.tfEnter.text = "CSO2_UI_CHANNEL_BAN";
            this.bg.gotoAndStop(1);
         }
         else
         {
             
             // Can we show the connection delay to the server with the following code?
             
            this.tfEnter.text = ShowPing + " Ms";
            this.bg.gotoAndStop(2);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With this example address - `127.0.0.1:30001`, can it show the value by pinging the game port?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you just measure time between the request and the answer. The exact details depend on what kind of communication you are dealing with.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var aTime:int = getTimer();
// You send request here.
// ...

// Server reply handler. It is an asynchronous URLLoader or Socket event.
function onReply(event:Event):void
{
    // Calculate and display the ping.
    var aPing:int = getTimer() - aTime;
    PingTF.text = "Ping: " + aPing + " ms.";
    
    // Handle the server answer here.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It shows as 0 ping, I think it's working. Can it query over an ip address to see if it's working correctly?

Comment: @Yusuf Under certain conditions (like being in control of the server or knowing how to communicate with it **AND** being able to resolve Flash cross-domain issues with that server), but yes, you totally can, whatever "*query over an ip address*" means.